# Sliding Image on Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Quite new to Sitecore. I need to develop a sliding image as shown on sitecore website below:
http://www.sitecore.net/

I'm cool with front-end Javascript. Could someone please help me design a template, items, components that's required to build on Sitecore? User should be able to change the images and text descriptions for the sliding content.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new **TemplateItem** called e.g. **SlideshowImageTemplateItem**.

It should have a set of **Fields** that are necessary: **Image**, **Description**, **Link**, etc.

Now each of the images in the slideshow should be a separate **Item** in **Sitecore** tree created using the **SlideshowImageTemplateItem**.

Then create sublayout **Slideshow** and add a **MultiList** field to its rendering parameters which will allow you to select which slides should be displayed in the particular slideshow.

Answer (score 1):

Did you take a look at the Nicam or JetStream demo sites available from [Sitecore Partner Network](http://spn.sitecore.net) (assuming you/your company have access)? Both have good examples of slider controls with editable text, all the Sitecore items and the related code to go with it. They also have the code changes required for a slightly different action in Page Editor mode, since you do not want the rotating action when you are editing.